# use the method - (void) dealloc for outlets

Tags: iphone

Good night!

Should I use the method - (void) dealloc in file ViewController.m for outlets (where `@synthesize` is announced at the beginning of the file) that do not have properties retained?

Answer (score 2):

In ARC, you do not need to implement `dealloc` other than to release resources managed outside of ARC (retained properties are managed by ARC). If you have a property that managed outside of ARC (say a `malloc`ed object), you need to free it in the `dealloc` method (preferably by setting it to `nil` and handling the freeing in the setter).

If you do implement `dealloc`, do *not* call super as you do when not using ARC.